# Data fetch not complete but complete function of subscribe firing

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

I have an Angular app which is doing:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._translationsService.getSegments()
        .subscribe(
        tus => this.transUnits = tus,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
        this.initialize
        );
```

In initialize() I have

```
initialize() {
    for (var tu of this.transUnits) {
        // try to iterate over array
    }
}
```

I keep getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at SafeSubscriber.TranslationEditor.initialize [as _complete] (translation-editor.component.ts:80)
```

presumably because the data response has not completed.

Should i set some kind of timeout for a few milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Javascript does not preserving the `this` argument when you are passing through a function reference. You need to either bind `this` to the call ala `this.initialize.bind(this)` or you need to call it with an arrow function which *does* preserve the closing scope.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._translationsService.getSegments()
        .subscribe(
        tus => this.transUnits = tus,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
        () => this.initialize
        );
```

[Reference](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)

Comment: Wow, thanks would never have found that.
    () => this.initialize
doesn't work: the initialize function is not called.
    this.initialize.bind(this)
does work.

Comment: I don't want to use an anonymous function because it does quite a lot of work.